# Are facebook User IDs (UIDs) a future proof key for Facebook Apps?

Tags: facebook, database-design

Will Facebook UIDs always be unique to one user?  For example, if a user permanently deleted their account, might Facebook reuse their UID for a new user? Or maybe even use it as the ID for something inanimate like the page for a City or a Local Business?  Can I use UIDs as the primary key for Users in a Facebook app without worrying about them being associated with something else in the future?

I haven't been able to find any documentation that guarntees that they will not be reused in the future.

This question more or less asks the same thing
( [Facebook app database issue: Store my own User ID or just use Facebook UID?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2682954/facebook-app-database-issue-store-my-own-user-id-or-just-use-facebook-uid) )
However, the answer does not provide any proof that UIDs will remain unique into the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by the Facebook UID.  If you are talking about the meaningless integer value associated with a user account, then you are probably OK.  If you are talking about the User Name, then that is a meaningful key and I think you need to be careful.

It doesn't matter if you can find a statement in the Facebook API documentation saying that it won't happen, signed in the blood of Mark Zuckerberg.  If you use a meaningful key value then there is always *some* risk that the key could change in the future.

The risk may be small.  The "future" may be longer than the scope of your application.  But sometime in the future Facebook may surely decide that they would like to reclaim a user ID that has been inactive or deleted so that someone else with the same name can have it.

Here is some [proof](http://techcrunch.com/2010/01/23/facebook-vanity-url-harman/) that it can happen.

If you somehow want to be sure that your application can tell the difference between this year's Facebook.com/Harman and next year's (or 2015's etc.) then you should keep your own meaningless PK and map it to the Facebook key along with an effective date range, like so:

```
FB_USER_KEY_MAP
  my_pk_value IDENTITY,
  fb_pk_value,
  effective_date,
  expiry_date
```

This is the only way to be *absolutely* sure that your PK is unique not only insofar as it only appears once in your table, but also insofar as it always refers to exactly the same person/account.

Comment: I think this is probably the best answer until Facebook comes out and explicitly says that they will never reassign UIDs. Though I didn't mean to come across like I was referring to the UID as being the User Name, I still think this answer helps everyone who's confused about this issue.  It provides a good method of protecting yourself against any changes FB might make to UIDs (because it's still possible, however unlikely).  It also contains the consensus of the other answers... will Facebook reassign UIDs? Probably not.

Comment: How do you know when to set the expiry date ?  And to what value ?

Comment: I would normally set the expiry date based on the insert of a conflicting external primary key value.  Whether you know the exact date or not depends on how intimately you know the external data source.  You could probably use the date and time your system first notices the conflict.  That should be good enough for any purpose within your own system.

Answer (score 1):

The UID will ALWAYS be unique.

It's common practice to set up your Primary Key (PK) as auto-incrememnet, which is classed as "the number of rows that have been created in this table", and takes no account of rows removed. Thus, even if you add 3 rows then delete them, the auto-increment is still set to 4, which will be the ID of the next row inserted.

This might be a case of "it's not documented anywhere, it's documented everywhere" :P It's one of those things that should always be implied; a PK will never be used twice for different things, ever. Full stop.

Comment: I think you're probably right, but I don't see anywhere in Facebook's documentation them even calling the UID their "Primary Key".  It sure looks like a primary key, but isn't it possible that they're using a different primary key in their databases that they don't show the public? I just think it would be nice if Facebook would make this important information explicit, regardless of how strongly it seems to be implied.

Comment: It's always possible, and you'll never know :) In terms of "how safe is it to assume this?", it's certainly pretty high, you're talking at LEAST 99/100. User ID is the "correct" value to set the PK on, so it *should* be safe enough.

Comment: Is there anywhere in Facebook's Documentation that describes the UID as the "correct" value to set the PK on?  Or do you mean that it's correct in the sense that it's common practice amongst Facebook developers

Comment: By "correct" I mean that as far as I'm aware, there's no good reason for having two unique columns to store a user's ID (duplication of data). If you're looking for some specific wording from me, you'll only get it if I happen to type the thing you're wanting to see. If I was writing any application where a user has an ID, that's the table's PK right there, every single time.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound as if I was criticizing your wording. Only asking for clarification.

Comment: I think that's more a case of me coming across sounding like a grumpy sod, when I didn't mean to :) Just trying to find the right words hehe.

Comment: haha, no problem.  It's easy to be misunderstood through writing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use data managed by somebody else, you are vulnerable to the possibiility that those people will screw up.

You would figure that Social Security number (SSN) would be unique to an individual.  But in decades long gone, the Social Security Administration actually assigned the numbers more than once.

Facebook is unlikely to screw this one up.  But it could happen, as the result of human error or even malice.